# SetOnClickListener in a ViewHolder in Kotlin Adapter

Tags: android-recyclerview, kotlin, adapter

I am trying to write my first `RecyclerView` custom adapter in Kotlin. Each `View` is pretty simple, it is a `CardView` with picture + name on it.

I am facing two problems:

ERROR 1 - `fun bindItems` is giving me error when i try the following to assign the name:

```
// THIS DOES GIVE ME ERROR, IT MARKS txvW_recycItem_userName IN RED
itemView.txvW_recycItem_userName = user.name

// HOWEVER THIS WORKS
val tvw_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txvW_recycItem_userName) as TextView
tvw_name.text = user.name
```

ERROR 2 - `onBindViewHolder` does not let me add a listener like this:

```
holder.bindItems(user[position])
holder.setOnClickListener{
        //do whatever
}
```

And here it is the complete code for the adapter:

```
 class CustomRecyclerAdapter(var user : ArrayList<Users>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int){
        holder.bindItems(user[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = user.size

        class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

            fun bindItems(user : Users){

                // HERE IT IS THE LINE DESCRIBED ON ERROR 1
                //itemView.txvW_recycItem_userName = user.name

                val image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgvW_mainPic) as ImageView
                val tvw_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txvW_recycItem_userName) as TextView

                tvw_name.text = user.name
                image.setImageResource(user.image)
            }
        }

    }
```

---

### **----> EDIT <----**

I am not sure if that is an answer for my ERROR 2 but...the following seems to be working:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener({
            // do something here
        })
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using setOnClickListener in adapter like this :

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(){

}
```

its perfectly working for me.

Comment: i think in first error you want to set text in textview Right? if yes then use this  

txvW_recycItem_userName.text =user.userName

Comment: ok i will try, It looks a bit strange not calling the `itemView` but...

Comment: i am afraid this is not working I still cant access the textview in the view layout unless i use findViewById